# Zero-padding a spinner in Java

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, zero-pad

How do you add zero padding to a `JSpinner`?
Since the spinner creates the `JFormattedTextField` itself, I can't just pass the format into the JFormattedTextField constructor.
Isn't there a way to set the formatting on an existing `JFormattedTextField`?

What I want:  value = 37, editor = "0037"

UPDATE:
I have tried this as suggested:

```
JSpinner mySpinner = new JSpinner();  
mySpinner.setEditor(  
    new JSpinner.NumberEditor(mySpinner, "####"));
```

and the result is no change at all to the presentation of the spinner's data.  It seems like a reasonable solution; has anyone tried this successfully so I can be sure it's just something flaky in my own application?

Comment: I had used it before; that's how I knew where to look. Let me do a little test with your code...

Comment: There, got it. Answer updated.

Comment: Yep, that definitely works - I was just about to post the same edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [set the editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#setEditor%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) yourself, like this:

```
// minimum of four digits
mySpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(mySpinner, "0000"));
```

`"0000"` is a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) string specifying four digits, zero-padded as necessary; `"####"` specifies four digits but does not zero-pad.

The [`DecimalFormat` API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) covers formatting strings in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the javadocs, JSpinner has a [setEditor(JComponent)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#setEditor(javax.swing.JComponent)) method.  Use that to set your custom JFormattedTextField, with its custom Format.